# How to create a request object?

Tags: lua, uwsgi, wsapi

I'm learning web development with lua (wsapi and uWSGI).
I'm trying to create a request object (https://keplerproject.github.io/wsapi/libraries.html) to see what it look like (and how to use it). So I've set up a example code :

```
require "wsapi.cgi"

function run(wsapi_env)
  local headers = { ["Content-type"] = "text/html" }
  local function hello_text()
    local result = "<html><body>\n"
    result = result .. "<p> Hello Wsapi !</p>\n"
    result = result .. "<p>PATH_INFO wsapi_env: " .. wsapi_env.PATH_INFO .. "</p>\n"
    -- problematic code
    local req = wsapi.request.new(wsapi_env)
    if req
    then
        --condition to see if req was nill
        result = result .. "<p>PATH INFO_POST : " .. req.POST .. "</p>\n"
        result = result .. "<p>PATH INFO_GET  : " .. req.GET .. "</p>\n"
    else
        result = result .. "<p> No request <\p>\n"
    end
    -- end of the problematic code
    result = result .. "<p><form method=\"post\" action=\"hello.lua\">\n"
    result = result .. "<textarea name=\"message\"> test </textarea>\n"
    result = result .. "</form></p>\n"
    result = result .. "</body></html>\n"
    coroutine.yield(result)
  end
  return 200, headers, coroutine.wrap(hello_text)
end
return run
```

But when I use the request object, the client receive a blank page.

How can I create and use a request object ?

Thanks you for your answers !

Extra question : How do I redirect to another page ( to a static page on the same domain ) ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this little code snippet will help:

```
local ws_request = require "wsapi.request"

function run(wsapi_env)
local qs = wsapi_env.QUERY_STRING
print("QUERY_STRING: " .. qs)
local req = ws_request.new(wsapi_env)
print(req.params.q)
end
```